# Python を使用したエクセルへの書き出し

Tags: python

ファイルメーカーからデータを csv でエクスポート、保存したのちにそのデータを元にPythonでエクセルにタイムスケジュールを作成したいと思っています。可能でしょうか？もし可能ならPythonのプログラミングをアドバイスくださる方がいらっしゃいませんでしょうか。

Comment: pythonでCSVの読み込みは可能ですし、Excelに書き出すことも可能です。ご自身で0から書き上げたコードを元に具体的な質問を別途挙げるのであれば、高確率で回答はもらえると思いますよ。

Comment: 「可能でしょうか？」可能か不可能かなら可能だと思います。「アドバイスくださる方がいらっしゃいませんでしょうか。」”アドバイス”とは何を求めているのでしょうか？「ファイルメーカーからデータを csv でエクスポート」とありますが、そのデータが不明な状況では具体的な回答は出来ないでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

可能です。Python は汎用のプログラミング言語なので、こういった事で出来無いことは有りません。ただし、特にエクセル形式は複雑なので、ライブラリを使用するのが一般的です。

- CSV: 標準ライブラリの [csv モジュール](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html) が使えます。
- エクセル形式: [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) というライブラリが有ります。これは標準ライブラリでは無いので、`pip` などでインストールします。